# Is there any way to make morris.js area chart gradient

Tags: jquery, charts, morris.js

I am using morris.js area chart to show weather report of a year.

Fiddle POC: http://jsfiddle.net/XtYr7/337/

SCRIPT:

```
Morris.Area({
 element: 'chart',
 data: [
 { m: 'Jan', value: 3 },
 { m: 'Feb', value: 10 },
 { m: 'Mar', value: 5 },
 { m: 'Apr', value: 17 },
 { m: 'May', value: 6 }
// till December 
 ],
 xkey: 'm',
 ykeys: ['value'],
 labels: ['Orders'],
 parseTime: false,
 lineColors:['#1E9CB5']
});
```

I want fill the area with gradient. Can anyone suggest me any workaround ?

Comment: drop some css in there

Comment: its an SVG generated by morris.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below method we can achieve the gradient fill

```
Morris.Area.prototype.fillForSeries = function(i)  
{
var color;
return "10-#3b7078-#b6b120:40-#bc951c-#3b7078:90-#3b7078";
}
```

Usage:

Gradients
Linear gradient format: “‹angle›-‹colour›[-‹colour›[:‹offset›]]*-‹colour›”, example: “90-#fff-#000” – 90° gradient from white to black or “0-#fff-#f00:20-#000” – 0° gradient from white via red (at 20%) to black.

radial gradient: “r[(‹fx›, ‹fy›)]‹colour›[-‹colour›[:‹offset›]]*-‹colour›”, example: “r#fff-#000” – gradient from white to black or “r(0.25, 0.75)#fff-#000” – gradient from white to black with focus point at 0.25, 0.75. Focus point coordinates are in 0..1 range. Radial gradients can only be applied to circles and ellipses.

Reference: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XtYr7/338/